# Load web pages with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to load full web pages with AJAX and how would I go about it?

I'm thinking that I can create individual pages as I normally would, and then use AJAX somehow to get that page, and present it where the user currently is. Is that the correct assumption to make?

Basically I'm aiming to make a more dynamic site, so when the user clicks an option it will scroll down and reveal the requested info, without a noticeable page redirect.

Any advice would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible but inadvisable - you're not leveraging any real benefit if you rewrite the whole page anyway. Your use case doesn't make it sound like you need to do this though, just modify a subsection of the page which is SOP for AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jquery's .load(url) method loads HTML direct into an element. So if you changed every <a> tag to be a .load() on your top-level element you could do this. It would be a bit like using frames, but targeting a DIV instead of a frame.

Of course it would break lots of things like the back-button, form handling etc etc unless you put a lot of work in.

So, like the doctor who when told "It hurts when I do this" replied "well don't do that then", the answer is probably "dont do that".

Comment: Yeah usability issues is one of the things I'm trying to keep in mind. It's good that you pointed out the back button.

Comment: Other concerns to keep in mind, depending on your target audience: users who don't have JavaScript enabled and (as a kind of subset of the first) search engine crawlers that don't use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to fetch the HTML and then write it into a div

Comment: This is the way I would probably do it too.

Comment: please provide further explanation or possibly an example for n00bs like me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You could create a page/site from pure JavaScript fetching all elements from a web service or similar handler. It's a nightmare to maintain though, and you run into all sorts of problems depending on your needs. I did it as an exercise in learning jQuery, AJAX and a few other things. I found form submissions became tricky. While the data is posted to a web service with AJAX, managing the state of the page became very convoluted, and it only got nightmarish as the needs of the site grew.

I also found that in order to accomplish this, you have to make a choice to refresh the entire interface during transitions or just the section being changed. Refreshing the entire interface is cumbersome and for "rapid" users, the AJAX may not be able to keep up. It also causes collisions on the web service requests. If your page has 4 separate sections being updated, it is not uncommon for a web service request to be "lost" in the middle leaving a section without an update.

So the answer to your question is "yes". Reading your question closely, I would keep the scope of your requests to individual display pages without much functionality. The simpler you keep it, the easier it is to maintain and use.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but this is a nice little script that can do the job. It can add ajax content loading to a existing non ajax site. Requires jQuery.

## Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Your navigation bar, can be "document" or body
var $navigation = $(".side");

//Your main content that will be replaces
var body = ".page";
var $body = $(body);

$navigation.delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    var newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if(newHash) {
        $body.fadeOut(200, function() {
            $body.hide().load(newHash + " " + body, function() {
                $body.fadeIn(200, function() {
                });
            });
        });
    };
});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');
</script>
```

## Details

All the links under $navigation will have a click event added to them that will update the window url hash. The window is listening for the hash change and will use the hash value to make an AJAX request to reload the $body html.

## Advantage

- History (Back & Forward) navigation will work:
- The same site will work with browsers that support JavaScript and browsers that don't;
- If you copy past the url the script will load the correct page;
- Because we are using the delegate function any links that are added via the result of the ajax load will also have the click event added to them

## Disadvantage

- You can no longer use anchors on your site

For more information and a example see: http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/85-best-practices-dynamic-content/

Comment: Cheers for the post, that looks interesting.